# Percipient vs Prescient

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, parts-of-speech

According to what I have come to understand, [*prescient*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prescient#Adjective) is an adjective meaning psychic but [*percipient*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/percipient#Noun) is a noun meaning a perceiver. So how can these two be synonyms?

Can anyone kindly explain to me the difference between these two words?

Comment: Have you looked at the respective dictionary definitions?

Comment: Similar words, not synonyms. Prescient emphasizes knowing things beforehand - predicting.

Comment: The root meaning of [percipient](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=percipient) is about perception, for [prescient](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=prescient) is about knowledge.

Comment: I have edited your question for formatting and clarity,. Please do not use the British English tag when you do not need it, like here, and especially please never use a space before a question mark in English, as we do not do that. Terminal punctuation (full stops, question marks, exclamation marks) and commas, colons, and semicolons are never preceded by a space in present-day (not Victorian) English orthography. However, in various closely related writing systems, such as that of French, some of these do work differently in that regard, so it is an easy mistake to make.

Comment: Yes. I have referred to various dictionaries like Cambridge, Oxford, Macmillan, and Collins. I'm very confused to see them as synonyms. They have completely different meaning, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you, @tchrist, for editing the question.

Comment: A helpful thesaurus will list words that are 'in a similar direction' and a dictionary can then be used to obtain the appropriate word. Personally I like a broad selection of words, so I can be reminded of possibilities (rather than learn new words).

Answer (score 2):

Both words **can** be used both as nouns and as adjectives. The only overlapping senses would likely occur in their uses as nouns, which are less common than their adjectival uses.

As an adjective, *percipient* today mostly means *perceptive*. The OED gives this meaning:

> That perceives or is capable of perceiving; conscious; perceptive, discerning.

That really doesn’t match with what *prescient* means. To find the purported synonymy, we must instead look to the noun senses. As a noun, *percipient* is restricted mainly to two specific domains, either philosophy or “**parapsychology**”:

> 1. Chiefly *Philosophy*. A person who or thing which perceives.
> 2. *Parapsychology*. A person who perceives something outside the range of the senses; a person with extrasensory perception.

It’s the second noun sense that aligns with people having prescience, worlds with seers and prophets, psychics and fortune tellers.

As for *prescient*, the OED provides two adjectival senses:

> 1. Having foreknowledge or foresight; foreseeing.
> 2. Of, relating to, or arising from prescience.

It is mainly in the speculative worlds of science fiction or fantasy that one encounters *prescient* used as noun to indicate a person with prescience, whether that’s Paul Atreides from *Dune* or Cassandra from the *Iliad*.* Those are where people who are called “prescients” would be like people called “psychics”.

Words with meanings similar to adjectival sense of *prescient* include *foreseeing, far-sighted, long-sighted, prevoyant, precognitive*.

Be aware that *prescients* the plural noun and *prescience* are pronounced identically, so it would be easy to mishear one for the other.

---

* BTW, *Atreïdes* also derives from the *Iliad*.

Comment: Words with meanings similar to adjectival sense of prescient... I would add _clairvoyant_.

Comment: *Prescient* is also used with less of a supernatural/psychic type meaning, occasionally in academic texts, where it is used when someone had a deep understanding of the long term trajectory of a situation, or the consequences of an action or policy, that wasn't apparent to anyone else. [Some examples can be seen here](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22proved+to+be+prescient%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

Prescient means being able to see, or at least anticipate, the future.  It comes from Latin words meaning foreknowledge.